# Extreme points of a closed unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis

H is the closed unit ball of $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ Show that the set of extreme points of H is Ex(H)= $\{\lambda_{e_n} : \lambda \in \mathbb{C }, |\lambda| = 1, n ≥ 1 \},$ where $(e_n)_{n\geq 1}$  the standard (unit vector) basis for $\ell_1(\mathbb{N}). $ and show that the closure of the extreme points is equal to $H  \cap c_e(\mathbb{N})$

Comment: what's $\lambda_{e_n}$? also, you should show your thoughts on the problem

Comment: Vector to the standard (unit vector) basis.

Comment: you probably mean $\lambda e_n$, not $\lambda_{e_n}$. i also dont know what "vector to the standard (unit vector) basis" means. sounds like word vomit

Comment: That might be true. I am just super lost

Comment: idk, maybe reread the book or find other references online.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$1).\ e_n$ is an extreme point for each integer $n$: suppose $0<t<1;\ x,y\in H$. Then, consider the components of $e_n=tx+(1-t)y$ to conclude.

$2).\ $ Suppose $x\in $Ex$ H$ but $x\neq \lambda e_n$ for some integer $n,\ |\lambda|=1.$ Then, $x$ has a component $x^{(m)}$ such that $|x^{(m)}|<1.$ Consider $y=e_m$ and $z=$ the sequence that is $0$ in the $m-th$ component and $\frac{x^{(n)}}{1-x^{(m)}}$ everywhere else. Note that $y$ and $z$ have norm $1$. To conclude, write $x$ as a convex combination of $y$ and $z$

Comment: I have a question about your second hint: I would write $x=x^{(m)}y+(1-x^{(m)})z$ but no one tells me that $0 < x^{(m)} < 1$

Comment: It follows from the hypothesis: wlog real components to make it easier to see.  We have $;\ |\lambda |=1$ and $\|x\|\le 1$, so if $x\neq \lambda e_n$ then either $x=\zeta e_n$ with $\zeta<1$ or  $x$ has at least two components so at least one if these components must be less than $1$

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't precise. I agree that $|x^{(m)}|<1$, but it doesn't need to be real. And I can't find any other $0 < \alpha <1$ such that $x=\alpha y +(1-\alpha)z$

Comment: But you can choose $\theta$ such that $e^{i\theta}x^{(m)}$ is real.